# Can't figure out why my stackviews are not arranging vertically

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller, uikit

I have done this many times but this time for some reason won't work the way it usually does. Am I doing something wrong here? I am just trying to get two views into my UIstackView and distribute them vertically. It seems to keep overlapping and going all over the place. At one point it was only even showing one view.

My viewdidload():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(contentStack)


        headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.30).isActive = true
        headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.70).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.90).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true



    }
```

My Views and Labels:

```
fileprivate lazy var headerView : UIView = {

        var view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        return view

        }()
    fileprivate lazy var contentView : UIView = {

        var view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return view

    }()

    fileprivate lazy var contentStack : UIStackView = {



        var stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [EarningsView,ListingsView,])

        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.axis = .vertical
//        stack.spacing = 5

        return stack

    }()
    fileprivate lazy var EarningsView : UIView = {

        let EarningsView = UIView()
        EarningsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        EarningsView.backgroundColor = .blue

         EarningsView.addSubview(EarningsLabel)
         EarningsView.addViewBorder(borderColor: UIColor.black.cgColor, borderWith: 0.5, borderCornerRadius: 0.0)

        return EarningsView

    }()
    fileprivate lazy var EarningsLabel : UILabel = {
        let EarningsLabel = UILabel()
        EarningsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let earningsText = NSAttributedString(string: "My Earnings", attributes: self.stringAttrib)
        EarningsLabel.attributedText = earningsText
        EarningsLabel.textColor = .black
        EarningsLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        EarningsLabel.textAlignment = .center


        return EarningsLabel

    }()

    fileprivate lazy var ListingsView : UIView = {

        let ListingsView = UIView()

        ListingsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        ListingsView.addSubview(ListingLabel)
        ListingsView.addViewBorder(borderColor: UIColor.black.cgColor, borderWith: 0.5, borderCornerRadius: 0.0)
        ListingsView.backgroundColor = .red
        return ListingsView
    }()
    fileprivate lazy var ListingLabel : UILabel = {
        let ListingLabel = UILabel()
        ListingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let listingText = NSAttributedString(string: "My Listing", attributes: self.stringAttrib)
        ListingLabel.attributedText = listingText


        return ListingLabel
    }()
```

This is driving me crazy because I have done it so many times before and now I have spent atleast 6 hours on this little part trying to figure it out. Of course I could just create a whole new viewcontroller but I just want to figure this out.[image: Screenshot of Overlapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EarningsView, EarningsLabel, ListingsView, ListingLabel have

`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

But they have no constraints added to replace the Autoresizing constraints, so they just act goofy and go up to the top left.  I've seen stuff like this before.  On my stuff.  Either autosize or put in constraints.

Comment: Hm when I take that out those views no longer show up

Comment: Ah... I had my stack view `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` which made it act that way.....